# Docker running script but server doesn't work

Tags: python, docker, encryption, dockerfile

I am doing an encryption service that everytime a user goes on the server it changes the key , the problem is that when i run the python file alone in works like this
[when it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6tLc.png)

but when I am dockerizing it by the below code

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir -p "C:\Users\joel\Desktop\mcast-freshers-week-devops-main\mcast-freshers-week-devops-main\encryption-service"

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


COPY . .
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

The build and run are succesful even the container it is being created , even the output from the python code is shown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMoKX.png)

but when i go to the server it shows this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TieZz.png)

I tried everything but I don't know what to do.

I treid changing the code many times but i still cant solve it , I narrowed it down because i tried another python application and it worked.

Comment: Unless you reconfigured things, your container has its own IP address.  It's not called "localhost".  You'll need to find its IP address.

Comment: Maybe a network issue. Please provide the output of `docker ps` while the container is running.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have the Windows path there?

Comment: how can i find it time roberts?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the Python code as well, and explain a little bit more about how it doesn't work?  You have a couple of links to images, but your question would be much clearer if you replaced them with the actual text of what the output is and the actual text of any error messages you're getting (not images and not links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your command with docker run, you can always expose the internal port on the docker container to match your local host network port, use this command instead for running your docker container

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 --name my-running-app my-python-app
```

You can then access your server by visiting localhost:8080

Comment: when i try it it says docker run requires at least 1 argument this is my code docker run -it --rm --name python-app -p 8080:8080

Comment: You did not specify the docker image in your command, based on the screenshots you provided you should run docker run -it --rm  -p 8080:8080 --name python-app  my-python-app

Comment: thankyou very much , just another question can I set the link in the dockerfile or do I have to always enter it in the terminal

Comment: Yes you can add this line to your dockerfile directly (EXPOSE 8080) this will by default expose the port.